# ADT Update in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

i have just recently updated my sdk and when i tried to open eclipse it gives me an error that adt is outdated and needs to update. i have searched for solutions here but nothing seems to fix mine. one solution was to manually download the update on eclipse->help->install new software and entered the url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ , after that i checked ADT version 23.0.4.1468518 for installation. but this solution doesnt work on mine. im having an error saying im having a conflicting dependency.

Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)

Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT XML Overlay 23.0.4.1468518 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.4.1468518)
    ADT XML Overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)

Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.4.1468518]

Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]

Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2

Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]

Comment: uninstall the existing adt and install the new

Comment: After updating the SDK, you must also do a `Help/Update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got these problems many times on my attempt to update adt.
Nothing worked for me, like "uninstall and reinstall adt plugin", "manual install" etc..

I had to download the latest adt bundle from developer.android.com and that seems to be the easiest way to get latest adt.

The adt plugin update worked fine on one of my development machines. But had to download fresh adt on another.

So I suggest you to download latest adt bundle if you are not getting it right on a few tries. At least that would save you some valuable time.

After downloading latest adt bundle, unzip it and just replace the eclipse folder in your current setup. This will keep all your already installed sdk components.

Answer (score 0):

```
Help --> Install New Software--> click what is already installed? uninstall ADT plugin

Help --> Install New Software -->add url --> http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

ADT 22.0.4 is designed for use with SDK Tools r22.0.4. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r22.0.4 into your SDK, use the Android SDK Manager to do so

What I had to do was update my ADT to 22.0.4 (Latest Version) and then I was able to update SDK tool to 22.0.4. I thought only SDK Tool has been updated not ADT, so I was updating the SDK Tool with Older ADT Version (22.0.1).

How to Update your ADT to Latest Version

In Eclipse go to Help

Install New Software ---> Add

inside Add Repository write the Name: ADT (or whatever you want)

Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

after loading you should get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins

check both if you want to use the Native Developer Kit (NDK) in the future or check

Developer Tool only

click Next

Finish
```